# Css change second element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know that:

```
p+p
```

changes the style of the first p just after another p. But how can I change the css of the second p after a p ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add another `+p`:

```
p+p+p
```

If you have more than three `p` elements, this applies to the second one that comes after the first, *as well as all subsequent elements*. If you only want to apply to one `p` element, use:

```
p:first-child+p+p
```

Or if you can afford to ignore older browsers:

```
p:nth-child(3)
```

Comment: And how can I do the p before another ?

Comment: Oh, then you can't do that; there's no such selector. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector